# Can't record actions within iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to automate a web-app the uses iFrames using Selenium v2.5.

Clicks on the base page record fine, but any clicks/actions to elements on the iFrames on that base page are ignored.

How can I get the IDE to follow me there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `selectFrame` to select different frames and select them by name or relatively travel them.

For instance something like:

```
Command        Target                    Value
-------        ------                    -----
selectFrame    name=iframe1
type           id=myInput                foobar
selectFrame    relative=up
click          css=input[type="submit"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but it still doesn't capture events when I'm clicking on the iFrame. Is there something I need to do while on the page in FFX to tell it to send messages to Selenium?

Comment: There's an [open issue about it](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6180), to be fixed in further releases. Until then you'll have to do this manually. How about loading the IFrame separately and recording the actions required for it, then adding those to your main test with manual control over when to jump to each frame?

Comment: How do I open the iFrame manually> Any idea of when it will be addressed?  Thanks!